# Calculate sum of 2D Arrays

Tags: kotlin

I want to write a program to calculate the sum of 2 matrices(2D Arrays) based on the user input.

Two matrices must have an equal number of rows and columns to be added. The sum of two matrices A and B will be a matrix that has the same number of rows and columns as do A and B.

The first line of standard input is a number of rows n and number of columns m of matrix A. Next n lines are A matrix’s elements. The next line after the empty line is a number of rows n and a number of columns m of matrix B. Next n lines are B matrix’s elements.

I want to output the result of a sum of A and B matrices or ERROR message if it’s impossible. The input contains only integers.

**Example**

```
Input:
4 5
1 2 3 4 5
3 2 3 2 1
8 0 9 9 1
1 3 4 5 6
4 5
1 1 4 4 5
4 4 5 7 8
1 2 3 9 8
1 0 0 0 1

Output:
2 3 7 8 10
7 6 8 9 9
9 2 12 18 9
2 3 4 5 7
```

My Code:

```
package processor

import java.util.*

val scanner = Scanner(System.`in`)

fun main() {
    MatrixProcessor().addition()
}

class MatrixProcessor {

    private fun createMatrix(): Array<Array<Int>> {
        val rows = scanner.nextInt()
        val columns = scanner.nextInt()
        return Array(rows) {Array(columns) { scanner.nextInt()} }
    }

    fun addition() {
        val firstMatrix = createMatrix()
        val secondMatrix = createMatrix()

        val sum = Array(4) { IntArray(5) }

        for (i in 0 until 4) {
            for (j in 0 until 5) {
                sum[i][j] = firstMatrix[i][j] + secondMatrix[i][j]
            }
        }
        printSolution(sum)
    }

    private fun printSolution(matrix: Array<IntArray>) {
        for (array in matrix) {
            for (value in array) {
                print("$value ")
            }
            println()
        }
    }
}
```

My main problem lies with sum in the addition function since I do not know how to fill it with dynamic row and column size and currently inserted a standard value of 4 and 5.

```
    fun addition() {
        val firstMatrix = createMatrix()
        val secondMatrix = createMatrix()

        val sum = Array(4) { IntArray(5) }

        for (i in 0 until 4) {
            for (j in 0 until 5) {
                sum[i][j] = firstMatrix[i][j] + secondMatrix[i][j]
            }
        }
        printSolution(sum)
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you're storing your matrices in row-major order: you have individual arrays representing rows, and then an outer array holding all the rows.  So **the size of the outer array gives you the number of rows, and the size of any of the inner arrays (such as the first) gives you the number of columns.**

So you can create the sum like this:

```
val sum = Array(firstMatrix.size) { IntArray(firstMatrix[0].size) }
for (i in sum.indices)
    for (j in sum[0].indices)
        sum[i][j] = firstMatrix[i][j] + secondMatrix[i][j]
```

(I've used `.indices` instead of an explicit range, for simplicity.)

An alternative approach is to specify the values when creating the arrays, instead of filling them in afterwards.  (It doesn't make too much difference here, as numeric arrays get a default value of 0; but it can simplify things a lot when creating arrays of a non-nullable reference type.)

```
val sum = Array(firstMatrix.size) { row ->
    IntArray(firstMatrix[0].size) { column ->
        firstMatrix[row][column] + secondMatrix[row][column]
    }
}
```

The Array() and IntArray() constructors pass the index into the lambda; while the first version ignores it, here we call it `row` or `columns` so we can use it to index the arrays we're summing.

---

The above assumes that all the inner arrays have the same size.  That's probably reasonable in this case, where you've created the arrays yourself — but in general you'd probably want to verify that.

Certainly, **it would be a good idea to verify that the two matrices you're adding are the same size**, and throw an IllegalArgumentException with a helpful message if not.  Otherwise, you'd either get an ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException (if the first were larger), or values would get silently truncated (if the second were larger) — both of which would be much harder to track down.

(The underlying issue here is that, like most languages, Kotlin doesn't have true two-dimensional arrays.  What it does have is arrays of arrays, which are more flexible — and therefore more dangerous.  If you were doing this properly, you'd probably wrap the array-of-arrays into your own Matrix class, which would always ensure that the data was properly rectangular, provide access to the row and column counts, and make all the necessary checks.)

Answer (score 0):

From what i've understood your problem is the fact that you must set a fixed size for Array. I suggest you to use ArrayList instead to solve the problem.

https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/-array-list/

With this solution you don't need to set a size for sum anymore.

Once you'll use ArrayLists you'll never get back to Arrays.